# TeXShop 4.27 on Mac deleting .bbl file while saving low-level tex-file

Tags: texshop

I'm currently writing my thesis using TeXShop and since the last update I noticed some strange behavior.

I am compiling my main file thesis.tex (in this order: LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX) which includes several low-level files (via \input{content/XYZ}). This works fine. But if I change one of the low-level files (e.g. content/XYZ.tex), TeXShop automatically deletes thesis.bbl when saving. Therefore, all my bibliography is gone and I have to redo the four steps.

Normally I am used to redo BibTeX, but only when the bibliography has changed. Why is TeXShop doing this? Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which version of TeXshop you employ. Do you employ the most up-to-date version, viz. 4.27? Please also clarify what you mean by "several low-level files (in this order: LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX)".

Comment: are you running any customized scripts?

Comment: No, I'm not running customized scripts. At least, none that I know of. How could I find out if there is one?

Comment: I don’t think TeXShop automatically deletes any files by default. Are you cleaning the auv files? How are you typesetting your document?

Comment: I can see the thesis.bbl file vanish when hitting CMD+S in TeXShop with XYZ.tex open. This does not happen while typesetting, only while saving the file...

Comment: I just tried it and when saving the the file that was input nothing happened to the root file's .bbl file. Could you make sure Cmd-S is assigned to something that simply does a Save? Also, is it really only the .bbl file that is removed? I'm using TeXShop 4.27 under macOS Mojave.